# "teenage boys" vs "teenaged boys"

Tags: grammaticality

https://www.lingq.com/cs/lesson/lesson-25-early-writing-431420/

> On the twelfth of September 1940, four **teenage boys** were exploring caves near ...

I guess in the above text, there is a mistake. I mean, I guess instead of "teenage boys" there should be "teenaged boys". Am I right or not?

Comment: If you followed your hunch with a little research, you'd see that [_teenage_ is an adjective](https://www.wordnik.com/words/teenage), so there is nothing wrong with using _teenage_ in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a [dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/teenage?q=teenage) will show that "[teenage](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/teenage?q=teenage)" and "[teenaged](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/teenaged?q=teenaged)" are both used in this sense.

You can say both "teenage boys" and "teenaged boys" with the same meaning.
The difference is that you can say "a teenage magazine" to mean "a magazine for teenagers", you can't say "a teenaged magazine".